# How to change default browser of Browsersync plugin for Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, browser-sync, sublime-text-plugin

I've installed the [Browser Sync plugin](https://github.com/iamdjones/sublime-text-browser-sync) for Sublime Text 3 using package control, but when I launch the plugin it opens Chrome browser by default(for Sublime Text 3 and OS I have Firefox as default browser).

How can I configure the plugin to open Firefox instead of Chrome by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sublime Text 3 go to `Preferences` -> `Browse Packages...`

Open '*Browser Sync*' folder and edit the `browser` property in *browser_sync_launch.js* file.

```
bs.init({
    server: args[0],
    files: args[1].split(','),
    index: args[2],
    startPath: args[2],
    logLevel: "silent",
    browser: "firefox"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating: In sublime 4 go to preferences -> Browser packages...
Open the 'Browser sync', in this case, the file to edit is browser_sync_launch.js